# Chrome doesn't see ASP.NET request verification token (__RequestVerificationToken) when debugging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry to add yet another request token post, but I've read through so many posts on this and none of them help!  I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and having lots of problems with the verification token when logging in.  This only happens in Chrome, and only while debugging on localhost.  In case it matters, I'm using https (automatic cert from VS) and VS 2015.

I'm getting:

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not
>   present

The top of the stack trace is:

> AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens

I know the drill.  The form has exactly one @Html.AntiForgeryToken(), there's no cross-domain issue, and I'm not redirecting to another method with it's own Validate attribute.  Full attributes on Login method (which is almost completely the out of the box login page and handler):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [RequireHttps]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

Clearing cookies doesn't fix it, and Fiddler verifies that the token hidden form field is being set and sent correctly.  This has been driving me crazy.

Comment: Is this https throughout? Or is `GET /Account/Login` http and `POST /Account/Login` https?

Comment: https on the GET and POST

Comment: Is chrome set to accept cookies?  Did you verify the cookie is being sent in the response and the POST?

Comment: Yes.  Verified in Chrome that cookie is set: ASP.NET_SessionId, __RequestVerificationToken, ai_session, ai_user, and something in Local Storage.

Comment: Great, I've got exactly that problem in .Net Core 2.2. And only on Chrome, and only on debug on localhost. Something weird is going on here...

Comment: I agree with the user "ExternalUse" who mentioned that this tends to be a problem in .Net Core. However, I don't think it is with .Net Core itself exactly. .Net Core tends to have a problem with Fiddler. One workaround to make requests show up in fiddler is to add a WebProxy: WebProxy proxyForFiddler = new WebProxy("127.0.0.0", 8888);
                request.Proxy = proxyForFiddler;